# How to have a Discord bot repeat message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am new to discord.js and making a bot, and I want to make a simple magic 8-ball style command where you ask the bot a question and it responds with a random answer.

```
const commands = [
new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('ask').setDescription('Ask MUDBot a yes or no question')
```

I have this in my deploy-commands.js and

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
const { commandName } = interaction;

if (commandName === 'ping') {
    await interaction.reply('Pong!');
} else if (commandName === 'ask') {
    switch (getRandomInt(10)) {
        case 0:
            //interaction.reply(client.message.content);
            //interaction.reply('You asked, I reply: ')
            
            await interaction.reply('It is certain!');
            break;
        case 1:
            //interaction.reply('You asked, I reply: ')
            await interaction.reply('Without a doubt.');
            break;
```

etc in my bot.js.

currently the output doesn't repeat the question you asked so if you say:
/ask are you a good bot?

the output is just:

... used /ask

MUDbot: (response)

How can I have the question you ask with the slash command be repeated by the bot?
Thank you.

Comment: You haven't set up a string option for the command, so your interaction has no context of any message being sent when it is invoked. Add a string option for the question then access it and concat the response

Comment: The guide will be useful: https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html

Comment: @Elitezen yes I understand that, I'm not sure where to add in the string option though. Is it a part of the slash command or somewhere else?

Comment: I didn't understand what the user is asking right now, and what is the bot answering? And what should he answer?

Comment: @HaimAbeles it can just take a generic question and give a generic answer, it chooses randomly from 10 answers. I am looking to have the bot repeat the question you ask it back to the user before giving the answer.

Comment: I don't see in your code at all that the bot is trying to answer what the user asked, am I missing something?

Comment: @HaimAbeles when the user puts in /ask it randomly selects from 10 generic answers and displays them, like a magic 8 ball. I'm just looking to have the bot display your question, basically repeat it back to you, before it gives the answer.

Comment: The guide I linked has everything you'll need, read through it

Comment: Thanks @Elitezen I think so. Unfortunately it's just more complicated than I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not seeing a way the user can actually ask the question itself, so a way of doing that is to add an [option](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#options).

```
const commands = [
new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('ask').setDescription('Ask MUDBot a yes or no question').addStringOption(option =>
    option.setName('question')
        .setDescription('The question that you want answered')
        .setRequired(true));
```

Then once you have the option on the slash command, get that when the command is ran and make a response string for it.

```
if (commandName === 'ask') {
    const question = interaction.options.getString('question');
    let response = `You asked "${question}", `;
    switch (getRandomInt(10)) {
        case 0:
            response += 'It is certain!';
            break;
        case 1:
            response += 'Without a doubt.';
            break;
    }
    // continue with other statements and then after switch reply
    interaction.reply(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what fetches the text the user sent to the bot

```
const message = await interaction.fetchReply();
//message.content is the user command
```

Then you can send the bot's answer in the following way:

```
const commandUser = message.content;

switch (getRandomInt(10)) {
    case 0:
        //interaction.reply(client.message.content);
        //interaction.reply('You asked, I reply: ')
        
        await interaction.reply(`commandUser: ${commandUser}, It is certain!`);
        break;
    case 1:
        //interaction.reply('You asked, I reply: ')
        await interaction.reply('Without a doubt.');
        break;
```

Comment: I am getting an invalid or unexpected token error: https://imgur.com/a/ZNCi758

Comment: Because of the stackoverflow code editor the character of the string was dropped, I fixed the code in the answer

Comment: I am getting this error in the terminal: https://imgur.com/a/dddo1wO

Comment: Can you please print the value of commandUser in the terminal and take a picture here?

Comment: I'm not too sure how to do that..

Comment: `console.log(commandUser)`

Comment: it doesn't appear to get that far in the code. I am wondering if this is maybe because I'm on a public wifi and will try on my home network when I get home.

Comment: Take a picture when you can of the first lines of the error that is printed to you in the terminal

Comment: That should be in the previous image, right after it says 'Ready!' would be the error